# use of '#undef' is discouraged: 'ssCmd' [MISRA 2012 Rule 20.5, advisory]

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

I am defining some macro - `#define` temporary inside code, which I have `#undef` after being used.

Is it not allowed to `#undef` MACRO?

```
void c_cmd(unsinged char *com)
{ 

int abc = com[0];
int res = 0;

switch(abc)
{
    case 1:
             #define ssCmd                 com[2]  /* SRT or STP*/
             res = abc + ssCmd;     
             /* part of some functionality */          

             #undef ssCmd 
             break;

    default:
             break;

}

}
```

Observed warning:

> use of '#undef' is discouraged: 'ssCmd' [MISRA 2012 Rule 20.5,
>   advisory]

Comment: Simply read rule 20.5, it's self-explanatory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do the MISRA rules prohibit the use of '#undef'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665031/why-do-the-misra-rules-prohibit-the-use-of-undef)

Comment: @P.W Nah that post is outdated since MISRA-C:2012 had not been released. The rule about `#undef` was relaxed in 2012.

Comment: related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769783/misra-c-2012-rule-20-5-undef-should-not-be-used

Comment: Use int ssCmd = com[2]; instead, and enclose the whole thing in {} to limit the scope of the variable.

Comment: Can I ask *why* you feel the need to `#define` and then `#undef` it?  Remember that these are *compile time* directives not run time.  And why not have the #define at the top of the file, and keep it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MISRA Rule 20.5 says that `#undef` should not be used. It's an advisory rule.

**Rationale**:
The use of `#undef` can make it unclear which macros exist at a particular point within a translation unit.

Comment: Is the *"`#undef` should not normally be needed"* a quote from MISRA? I can't find this wording in the 2019 revision of MISRA C:2012.

Comment: Good point, try to make the wording clear.